# Combining queried objects into a single array. Code finds followed users then their posts, it returns the posts separately per user, how to combine?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

The code below queries "followers" to see if a user is following another and then if they are it queries "Post" to find post from the users they are following. Currently the logged in user is following 2 other users, user A and user B. A has 1 post and B has 2 posts. For some reason when I run the second set of codes below, it returns the counts separately. The println shows the post count by individual user. I need the count to be the sum of all posts found. It seems that there is 2 arrays of posts because there are 2 users followed. How do I combine these 2 arrays?

```
var getFollowedUsersQuery = PFQuery(className: "followers")

        getFollowedUsersQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)

        getFollowedUsersQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objectos, error) -> Void in

            if let objectos = objectos {

                for objecto in objectos {

                    var followedUser = objecto["following"] as! String

                    var query = PFQuery(className: "Post")

                    query.whereKey("userId", notEqualTo: currentuser.objectId)

                    query.whereKey("userId", equalTo: followedUser)

                    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            self.postsArray.removeAllObjects()
                            self.postsFound.removeAllObjects()


                            let array:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: objects)
                            let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
                            dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue() , { () -> Void in
                                fn(array)
                            })

                        } else {
                            println(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
```

And when I run

```
self.postsFound.addObjectsFromArray(array as [AnyObject])
self.totalUsers = self.postsFound.count
println("Total Posts found \(self.postsFound.count)")
```

The println  is returning:

Total Posts found 1

Total Posts found 2

I want all the posts found to be in 1 array and have the println return:

Total Posts found 3

Answer (score 1):

The best option from a query point of view would be to make only 1 query and include your followers query as a requirement of that query. In this way you would be asking for all of the posts whose author is a followed user. This is looking at the problem backwards compared to find all followed users and then find their posts. As its a composite request it's more efficient and returns a single list.

Note that there are limitations... Yhe inner query will be limited to 1000 followers (100 by default), and you would need to add a sort to get sensible results from the outer query.

Continuing with your current query setup can help you avoid these query limit restrictions, but you need to organise building a single array of results yourself. It would be best to do that in cloud code and use promises to wait for all of the requests to complete.

This is all quite general I'm afraid, but you need to decide on an appropriate approach depending on what you're actually using this data for and how many users you're expecting to have...